# HealthKit how to get distance and pace

Tags: apple-watch, watch, healthkit

I'm writing a watch app and I'm trying to find the best way to get distance and pace for current `HKWorkoutSession`.

I can get steps from `HealthKit` and use it as a source of `distance` and `pace` but I don't think it's the best solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think `HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)` is exactly what I'm looking for.